# Как вывести записи(см. вложение) wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал произвольный тип записи, в файле шаблона вывожу их в три колонки. Мне необходимо сделать, чтобы после ряда колоночных записей вывелись те же записи три записи но с другими критериями. И так каждый раз для каждого ряда. Те дублирующие записи под рядом будут скрыты через, display: none b и вызываться при клике. Посмотреть, как это устроено можно на: http://www.staron.com/staron/eng/contents/exhibition/list.do

На данный момент имею следующий код для шаблона(но он выводит записи в три колонки, а как после каждого ряда вставить теже записи что и в ряду не могу сообразить):

```
<div class="container">

<?php 
    $count = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' =>  -1,
        'post_type' => 'gallery',
    );
    $gallery = new WP_Query( $args );
    $arr = $gallery->have_posts();
    if($gallery->have_posts()) :
    while($gallery->have_posts()) :
            $gallery->the_post(); 
?>
            <div class="col-1 boxes<?php if( $count%3 == 0 ) { echo '-1'; }; $count++; ?>">
                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <figure class="indent-bot">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(380,220,true)); ?>
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="col-1-content">
                        <strong class="title-3">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .entry -->
                    </div><!-- .col-1-content-->
                </div><!-- .post -->
            </div><!-- .boxes -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: В примере по вашей ссылке записи запрашиваются с сервера и выводятся аджаксом, а не хранятся в скрытых блоках. Имхо, этот путь в данном случае более оправдан

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавлять необходимый контент во временную переменную, а потом выводить её содержимое в нужном месте:

```
<?php 
    $count = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' =>  -1,
        'post_type' => 'gallery',
    );
    $gallery = new WP_Query( $args );
    $arr = $gallery->have_posts();
    $hidden_content = '';
    if($gallery->have_posts()) :
    while($gallery->have_posts()) :
            $gallery->the_post();
            $hidden_content .= '<h1 class="post-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1><div class="post-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
?>
            <div class="col-1 boxes<?php if( $count%3 == 0 ) { echo '-1'; }; $count++; ?>">
                <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <figure class="indent-bot">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(380,220,true)); ?>
                        </a>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="col-1-content">
                        <strong class="title-3">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .entry -->
                    </div><!-- .col-1-content-->
                </div><!-- .post -->
            </div><!-- .boxes -->
        <?php
            if( $count%3 == 0 ) {
                echo $hidden_content;
                $hidden_content = '';
            }
        ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php
        if( !empty($hidden_content) ) {
            echo $hidden_content;
        }
    ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```